# MySQL: help needed in query for 4 tables. Looking for id's present in all tables and want to list only the most recent date

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables with the same column names id and date.  What I am trying to do is get all the id's that appear in all 4 tables and only list the common id by the most recent date.

For example:

```
A
id date
1  11/30/02
1  10/01/02
2  11/15/05
4  12/01/03

B
id date
1 11/30/02
1 10/01/02
3 12/1/05
4 12/01/03

C
id date
1  11/30/02
4  12/01/03

D
id date
1  11/30/02
4  12/01/03
5  09/01/02
```

Now what I want is to run a query and create another table that will look like this:

```
E
id date
1  11/30/02
4  12/01/03
```

I have tried many things and have had no luck with any of them.  I would appreciate any help.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

E.g.

```
SELECT a.id
     , MAX(GREATEST(a.date,b.date,c.date,d.date)) date 
  FROM a 
  JOIN b 
    ON b.id = a.id 
  JOIN c 
    ON c.id = a.id 
  JOIN d 
    ON d.id = a.id
 GROUP
    BY a.id
```

or maybe...

```
SELECT id,MAX(date) date
  FROM
     ( SELECT tbl
            , id
            , MAX(date) date
         FROM 
            ( SELECT 'a' tbl, id, date FROM a
              UNION 
              SELECT 'b', id, date FROM b
              UNION 
              SELECT 'c', id, date FROM c
              UNION 
              SELECT 'd', id, date FROM d
            ) x
        GROUP 
           BY tbl
            , id
      ) y 
  GROUP 
     BY id
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 4;
```

Of course, these solutions assume that your dates are stored with a DATE data type.

Comment: You probably missed a d.date.. Anyways +1

Comment: yes - actually, I made a couple of errors (hopefully now fixed)

Comment: But not the first? !?!

Comment: @Strawberry, I didn't try the first.  But I have another question.  What I am getting is all the id's returned where all are included in each table at some point regardless of date and then the most recent date is given.  However I would like to change this so that I get the id's where all are included in each table at the same most recent date.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table E as 
select id, max(date) from (
select id, date from A
union all 
select id, date from B
union all 
select id, date from C
union all 
select id, date from D
) tmp group by id
having count(1) = 4
```